# Cannot change First/Last name order in Google Contacts when the sytem language is Hungarian

Tags: contacts, google, google-contacts

I took a screenshot of the settings page of Google Contacts with both languages.

As you can see in the Hungarian version the "Sort by", and "Name format" options are missing. Is there any way I could change those options and have the system language set to Hungarian?

(I already tried changing them and then switching back to Hungarian but it reverted the changes)

[image]